# Trouble with notches ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to create a notched boxplot in ggplot2, thus:

```
m <- ggplot(dat, aes(y = Slope, x = factor(BB),
fill=factor(BB)))


m + geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE)
```

However the plot produced is just a normal boxplot without notches.  Has anyone encountered this issue before?  Is there a way around it?  I'm not sure if i'm missing something really obvious here!

I cna't put my own data up but I am getting the same result with the example dataset from ggplot2:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE, notchwidth = .3)
```

My session info is:

```
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] splines   grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods       base     

other attached packages:
 [1] mgcv_1.7-6       gam_1.06.2       caper_0.5        mvtnorm_0.9-9991 MASS_7.3-13          ape_3.0-1       
 [7] ggplot2_0.8.9    proto_0.3-9.2    reshape_0.8.4    plyr_1.7.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.5.1       gee_4.13-17        lattice_0.19-33    Matrix_0.999375-50     nlme_3.1-101      
[6] tools_2.13.1
```

Comment: Give us the data on which you see no notches. Give us your `sessionInfo()`. I've no problem on my test data (0.93.1).

Comment: Hi Arun.  thanks for your comment.  I can't put my own data up, but I have tried the same with the example data as part of ggplot 2 and I still don't get notches.  I've edited my post above with info on this...

Comment: update your ggplot2. you're using 0.8.9. I presume that's the issue.

Comment: @Arun could you add that as an answer?

Comment: It looks like your R version is extremely old as well (`tools_2.13.1`?). I would update R and then reinstall/update everything.

Comment: Oh!  Thank you :-).  The problem was that I was stupidly using an old version of R so the downloaded vers of ggplot2 was the older one compatible with that!  Shall I delete this question so it does not clutter more useful ggplot questions?!

Comment: Hi Joran, thank you - I just spotted that myself.  How silly of me.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that your problem is because you are using an older version of ggplot2. Noting @joran's comment, I'd also recommend to update R first before updating packages.

Then, you can install/update `ggplot2` and all its dependencies by:

```
install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Hope this helps.